# proof of every continuous function on closed interval is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to teach myself real analysis but I faced some difficulty understanding this lemma.

I can't understand why the sequence $$x_n >n$$ is defined

[image: lemma 3.10]

isn't that enough to simply say assume that one point $$f(x_0)> n$$ then the any sequence that converge to this point in the domain of the function then this contradict that the function is continuous and how do we know that there is many $$f(x_n) >n $$ for all $n$ why doesn't that be one point in the domain that has this property not infinity many of them
and I am sorry if the question looks stupid but this subject is new to me.

Comment: One point being greater than $n$ doesn't contradict continuity. For example the function $f(x)=x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ has a point greater than $n=0.5$ and yet it's continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your questions correctly but here we go:

- As for the first question, note that when we say a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is unbounded, we usually mean that $\forall M \in \mathbb{R}^+,  \exists s \in S: M < |s|$, but not the other way around, i.e. $\exists s \in S, \forall M \in \mathbb{R}^+: M < |s|$. Loosely speaking, that is to say that the $s$ which helps you "violate" boundedness can depend on the bound $M$. So there isn't an "omnipotent" element in $S$ that is bigger than every $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Based on this, you can't simply take an element $x_0$ whose image is bigger than every natural number $n$, as it is not what the definition of unboundedness gives you. (On a shorter note, could such a real number $s$ that is bigger than every other real (natural) number exist? We know that $s+1 \in R$! For the natural case, assuming that $s$ is positive, take $\lfloor s \rfloor + 2$.)
- As for the second question, let's assume that all $x_n$ are equal to say, $x$. Then $y := f(x)$ is a fixed value and based on my answer to your first question, such a $y$ would be that "omnipotent" element which is bigger than every $n$, which does not exist. The reason there are infinitely many of these is that for each $n$, unboundedness guarantees (just take $M = n$) that there absolutely exists a $y_n$ that is bigger than $n$. These $y_n$ are in the image of $f$, so there exists for each $y_n$ at least one $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$.

Comment: thank you for your clear answer it is very helpful

Comment: @Ahmed Glad my answer was of help to you!

Answer (score 4):

The idea of these kind of arguments is to assume that the statement we want to proof is false and then try to find a contradiction. The statement is
$$\text{There exists an } M \ge 0 \text{ such that } f(x) \le M ~~\forall x \in [a, b].$$
Saying that this statement is wrong amounts to say that
$$\text{For every } M \ge 0 \text{ there exists  } x_M \in [a, b] \text{ and } f(x_M) > M.$$
Assuming this, you can take in particular $M = n \in \mathbb N$. Then for every $n \in \mathbb N$, there is $x_n \in [a, b]$ such that $f(x_n) > n$. This gives us a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that, for every $n \in \mathbb N$, $f(x_n) > n$. Then you can use the Sequential Compactness Theorem on the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ to deduce the desired contradiction.